# summing the elements of two lists without using a function ( python)

Tags: python, list

listone = []

listwo= []

adding = [0] * 10

for c in range (0, 10):

```
listone = (int(input('Type 10 values: ')))
```

for d in range (0, 10):

```
listwo = (int(input('Type 10 more values: ')))
```

for i in range (0, 10):

```
adding[i] = listone[i] + listwo[i]
```

print(adding)

I changed now so the user has to insert the values and it doesn't work. Cannot use any methods, so it's not similar to the other one stack is alerting me.

Help?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace 'adding = [ ]' with:

```py
adding = [0] * 10
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```py
adding = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I changed now if you could please take a look, ended up with another error

Comment: Please post the error